# pandas group by on a subset returns wrong number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am dramatically simplifying this question (compared to the initial draft).

Given a dataframe with a categorical type, if I subset the dataframe so it only contains a few of the categorical values, the subsetted dataframe still remembers the full list of category levels.

When I `groupby` on this, smaller, dataframe, I continue to get values which I don't expect.

Here is some code which replicates this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colA':['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 
    'colB':1
})
df['colA'] = df['colA'].astype('category') #<= this is important
df
```

output

```
    colA    colB
0   a   1
1   b   1
2   b   1
3   c   1
4   c   1
5   c   1
```

```py
df.groupby('colA').max()
```

output

```
colB
colA    
a   1
b   1
c   1
```

```py
smalldf = df.iloc[:3]
smalldf['colA']
```

output

```
0    a
1    b
2    b
Name: colA, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Notice above that 'c' is still in the category levels

```py
smalldf.groupby('colA').max()
```

output

```
    colB
colA    
a   1.0
b   1.0
c   NaN
```

This 'c' here is unexpected. However, I suppose it can be explained away because subsetting doesn't remove the category levels.

The problem gets worse when you write out the smaller dataframe

```py
FEATHER_PATH = Path.joinpath(Path.home(), 'Downloads', 'test.feather')
smalldf.to_feather(FEATHER_PATH)

pd.read_feather(FEATHER_PATH)['colA']
```

```
0    a
1    b
2    b
Name: colA, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Say you write out the smaller dataframe and pass it to someone. They take a look at the file and only see `colA` values of 'a' and 'b'. However, when they do a groupby, 'c' shows up. 'c' is no where to be found in the actual data!

They would have to explicitly look for category levels to find the 'c' hidden in there!

I'm not sure if this behavior is wrong, but can certainly can be extremely confusing!

Not sure if this can be left here as a warning to others.

Comment: You should provide the full explicit code

Comment: @mozway: good suggestion, added a reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not wrong, but it is a bit hidden in the docs. You can find it for example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#operations):

> DataFrame methods like DataFrame.sum() also show “unused” categories.

> Groupby will also show “unused” categories

Regarding the writing/reading: Without it you would loose type information, which might hurt as well. So there's a tradeoff to balance.

You should be able to handle it by using the `observed=True` option of [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> **observed: *bool, default False***
>
> This only applies if any of the groupers are Categoricals. If True: only show observed values for categorical groupers. If False: show all values for categorical groupers.

For example:

```
smalldf.groupby('colA', observed=True).max()
```

delivers

```
      colB
colA      
a        1
b        1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, the length of the DataFrame based on `groups.get_group('colA')` will have the same length as the unique values of the 'colA' column.

Edit: That assumes that 'colA' is your biggest column.

Comment: But groupby is returning unique values of the original table, not the subsetted data!
Say I have data about all the cities in the US. I then limit the dataframe to Michigan, do a group by, but it starts showing my New York, LA, Denver, etc.

Comment: "groupby" doesn't return values, it returns a group of dataframes. "get_group" returns dataframes. You didn't even show your entire code for us to see where this length is coming from. If you do groupby for 'colA' and that column has 2920934 unique values (not counting NaN for example, because that doesn't work with groupby), get_group('colA') will return a dataframe with minimum of 2920934 length. It's simple.

Comment: @luka1156 please provide the code to create your sample dataframe :)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html. Here it is.